# let-over-lambda in Scheme?

Tags: lambda, scheme, chicken-scheme, let-over-lambda

In Common Lisp, if I want two functions to share state, I would perform a *let over lambda* as follows:

```
(let ((state 1))
 (defun inc-state ()
  (incf state))
 (defun print-state ()
  (format t "~a~%" state))
```

These functions are not local to the `let` - they are global functions that maintain a reference to a shared *state* variable, which itself is not visible from outside. For example, I could do the following elsewhere in my code:

```
(print-state)       => 1
(inc-state)         => 2
(print-state)       => 2
```

In Scheme, however, such a construct declares *local functions*, that are not visible from outside:

```
(let ((state 1))
 (define (print-state)
  (print state))

 (print-state))     => 1

(print-state)       => error, no such variable print-state
```

The only way I can think to achieve this kind of functionality (aside from using un-exported globals inside a module), would be something like this:

```
(define print-state #f)
(define inc-state #f)

(let ((state 1))
 (set! print-state (lambda () (print state)))
 (set! inc-state (lambda () (inc! state))))
```

Is there a way in Scheme to write the *let-over-lambda* form without resorting to such ugly workarounds? Or would I need to write a macro to wrap this ugliness? (Btw I know about `letrec`, and that's not a solution to this problem.)

Incidentally, I'm using Chicken Scheme, but my question should be relevant to all Schemes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately top level binding can only be made top level and `define` inside a procedure is actually just syntactic sugar for a `letrec`. In Chicken Scheme you have a form called `define-values` where you can do this:

```
(define-values (print-state inc-state)
  (let ((state 1))
    (values (lambda () (print state))
            (lambda () (inc! state)))))
```

Note that `define-values` is not part of any standard even though it seems it's common form to have. It would be easy to make a macro that uses the approach you used to implement it though. For an alternative solution you can return a dispatcher that you call to get access to procedures:

```
(define dispatcher
  (let ((state 1))
    (lambda (msg)
      (case msg
        ((print) (lambda () (print state)))
        ((inc!)  (lambda () (inc! state)))))))

(define print-state (dispatcher 'print))
(define inc-state (dispatcher 'inc!))
```

In reality you don't need to make globals since you can just call the return directly:

```
((dispatcher 'inc!))
((dispatcher 'inc!))
((dispatcher 'print)) ; ==> prints 3
```

Comment: Thanks. `define-values` is less ugly than my solution. I'll still probably write a macro to wrap it though.

Comment: `define-values` is specified in R7RS section 5.3.3.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```
(define-values (inc-state print-state)
  (let ((state 1))
    (values
     (lambda () ; inc-state
       (set! state (+ 1 state)))
     (lambda () ; print-state
       (display state)
       (newline)))))

> (print-state)
1
> (inc-state)
> (print-state)
2
> state
. . state: undefined; cannot reference an identifier before its definition
>
```

*(output is from Racket but I tested it in Chicken Scheme as well)*